# Is it possible to check private key syntax using openssl?

Tags: openssl, pkcs8

I have a DER-serialized private key. The tool I have to provide the key to gives me `algid parse error, not a sequence`, and it looks like the problem is that [the key is not PKCS#8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6560187/2612143).

The command that [the most popular comment to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559272/algid-parse-error-not-a-sequence#comment7735521_6560187) suggests, worked for me - I got a PKCS#8 key and the tool accepts it.

Now I am curious how can I find out whether the key is PKCS#1, PKCS#8 or something else?

Comment: Hello, you might have better luck at https://security.stackexchange.com/, this site leans more towards the theoretical aspect of cryptography

Comment: `openssl asn1parse -inform der -in $file` will show the exact data structure, which you (or we) can match to potential specs. But I concur this is better suited to security.SX.